# Javascript Facebook api -- list of friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect to facebook via javascript to create an api that will list a set of names/pictures of the person from a string of facebook id's

So I want to push an array of ids [id1,id2,id3] -- into the graph api to find out the names and pictures of the people as a list.

latest jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/74/

-- I've started to try and make the application but its coming up with the error

""An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.""

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var app = {
            getFriends : function(){
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name', function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    if(response.data) {
                        $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                            alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
          $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
            FB.init({
              appId: '803898723110754',
              version: 'v2.7' // or v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, ...
            });     
            $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
            FB.getLoginStatus();

            app.getFriends();
          });
        });


        //app id
        //803898723110754

        //client token
        //a10b3f9479bac9cce58aeecd8a037a04


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "test";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see you using any access token whatsoever? I did a little searching and it might help to add `?access_token=` to the endpoint. I've never worked with the Facebook API before so I might be completely wrong though.

Comment: _ to which end point -- the /me?

Comment: I think I did create a function to try and get the access token -- new error -- ""Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error."

Comment: Try to find the error on here. https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/docs/errors/

Comment: "Your Access Token is either incorrect, invalid or expired" -- lol but it goes off to try and fetch it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/74/

Comment: That’s still the wrong approach completely. Your app secret must not be exposed in client-side code, ever. That endpoint your are trying to get a token from there, is only for _app_ access tokens. And your “client id” is not an app id, but a user id. That’s not how this works at all.

Comment: @CBroe - what should it look like?  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/74/

Comment: You should go reset your app secret right now ... Again: Those should not ever be exposed to the public; everyone can take them and use them as a valid app access token for your app, performing all kinds of actions in its name. And then, start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: It doesn't even work